# I need a solution for this puzzle

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

This is meant to be a simple puzzle

Given that:

3 - 4= -1

5 + 3= 7

2 + 6= 15

30 / 6= 20

Find: 20% of the sum for the final answer

Hint:

> Order of operations

Final Answer Format: 00/0=0

(/ = ÷) (Divide Symbol)

Comment: The sum of what?

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer (I don't think so at least), but maybe something someone can build off of:

> $3-4=-1$ is correct, so we move on to $5+3$ where the answer is $8$ and add the $-1$ to get $7$. Then do the same for the others, $2+6=8$, $7+8=15$, and $30/6=5$, $5+15=20$. Not sure what 'the sum' means or how to incorporate the clue.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for

> 20% of the last answer (even though it’s not a sum?) but it’s a cumulative response.

We note that

> 3-4 = -1, then there’s a carryover effect: 
>  5 + 3 = 8 - 1 from above = 7. Similarly 
>  2 + 6 = 8 + 7 = 15, and 
>  30 / 6 = 5 + 15 = 20.

Then

> 20% of 20 is given as 
>  20 / 5 = 4 + 20 from above = 24.

So the final answer is

> 20 / 5 = 24?

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: I am stuck where you are... tempted to flag this 'unclear what you are asking'...